# Transforming a non-invertible matrix into an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, matrix-inverse

Given a non-invertible, diagonalizable matrix $A$, I wish to transform it into another matrix $B$ that satisfies:

- $B$ is invertible
- all non-zero eigenvalues of $A$, are also eigenvalues of $B$
- all of the eigenvectors correspond to non-zero eigenvalues of $A$, are also eigenvectors that correspond to the same eigenvalues of $B$

There are no other constraints on $B$.

What is the simplest way to calculate such a matrix $B$? (of course, there are infinitely many such matrices, but I want an easy way to calculate some such a matrix $B$).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the projector onto $\mathop{\rm Ker} A$ along $\mathop{\rm Im} A$...

Comment: Let $f(T)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$ with all the factors of $T$ divided out, and take $B=A+f(A)$.

Comment: Ilya: the matrix $A$ is not necessarily *orthogonally* diagonalizable.  Consider, e.g., $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, which is perfectly diagonalizable with null space in the anti-diagonal direction; Yet, you can check that $B = A + \text{Proj}_{N(A)}$ no longer has the eigenvector $(1,0)^T$ of $A$, since $(1,0)^T$ has a component in the anti-diagonal direction.

Comment: @Nawai: My projector is not orthogonal: it is _along_ $\mathop{\rm Im} A$, so all the vectors in the image are mapped to zero.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov can you specify your B for the 2x2 example from my previous comment?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee: the projector is $\left[\begin{matrix}0& -1\\0& 1\end{matrix}\right]$: it maps $(1,0)^T$ to $0$, but $(1,-1)^T$ to itself. The result is thus $\left[\begin{matrix}1& 0\\0& 1\end{matrix}\right]$.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: so this projector **obliquely** projects onto the kernel of A along the image of A.  That makes perfect sense now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here we expand a bit on Ilya Bogdanov's answer: $B = A + \Pi$, where $\Pi$ is the oblique projection matrix onto the null space of $A$ along the column space of $A$.

**Oblique Projection Matrix**

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with rank $r$.  Compute its leading $r$ left singular vectors $\{ \vec{u}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid 1 \le i \le r \}$.    The oblique projection matrix onto the null space of $A$ or $\text{Null}(A)$ along the column space of $A$ or $\text{Col}(A)$ is:
$$
\Pi = I_n - \sum_{1 \le i \le r} \vec{u}_i \vec{u}_i^T \;. \tag{$\star$}
$$

*Computational Cost of Constructing Oblique Projection Matrix*

Note that computing this projection matrix only requires computing a **compact SVD**, i.e., finding the positive eigenvalues $\{ \lambda_i \}$ of $A^T A$ and their associated eigenvectors $\{ \vec{v}_i \}$.  Then set 
$$
\vec{u}_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}} A \vec{v}_i   \tag{$\diamond$}
$$
for $1 \le i \le r$.

*Why does ($\star$) work?*

Recall that the left singular vectors are an orthonormal basis for $\text{Col}(A)$. Thus, one can always write the projection as:
$$
\Pi \vec{x} = \vec{x} -\sum_{1 \le i \le r} \alpha_i (\vec{u}_i \bullet \vec{x}) \vec{u}_i
$$
where the scalars $\{ \alpha_i \}$ are determined such that $\Pi \vec{x} \in \text{Null}(A) = \text{Null}(A^TA)$.  In particular, 
$$
(A A^T \vec{u}_j) \bullet ( \vec{x} - \sum_{1 \le i \le r} \alpha_i \vec{u}_i ) = 0 \implies \alpha_i = \vec{u}_i \bullet \vec{x} \quad \text{for $1 \le i \le r$}
$$
which gives the oblique projection map in ($\star$).

**Transformed Matrix**

Ilya proposed to the transform $B=A + \Pi$.  This works because if $\vec{x}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with nonzero eigenvalue then clearly $\vec{x} \in \text{Col}(A)$ and
$$
B \vec{x} = A \vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x}
$$
On the other hand, if $\vec{x}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with a zero eigenvalue then $\vec{x} \in \text{Null}(A)$ or $\vec{x} \perp \text{Col}(A^T)$, and hence from ($\diamond$),
$$
B \vec{x} = \vec{x}
$$
So, $B$ fulfills the OP's desiderata.

**MATLAB Implementation**

One can replace $A$ below with any diagonalizable matrix.

```
% construction

A = [1 1 1; -2 -2 -1; 0 0 -1];
[n,n]=size(A);
r=rank(A);
[U,S,V]=svds(A,r);
B=A+(eye(n)-U*U');

% verification

[vectorsA,valuesA]=eig(A);
[vectorsB,valuesB]=eig(B);

valuesA=diag(valuesA);
ix=~(valuesA==0);
valuesA=valuesA(ix);
vectorsA=vectorsA(:,ix);

for i=1:length(valuesA)
  B*vectorsA(:,i)-valuesA(i)*vectorsA(:,i)
end
```